# url rewrite on sun web server 7

Tags: url-rewriting, kohana

I am developing a php application with Kohana framework which enables url rewriting by default.

I need to translate these rules defined in the htaccess file but I can't figure it out.

```
# Turn on URL rewriting
RewriteEngine On

# Installation directory
RewriteBase /kohana/

# Protect hidden files from being viewed
<Files .*>
 Order Deny,Allow
 Deny From All
</Files>

# Protect application and system files from being viewed
RewriteRule ^(?:application|modules|system)\b index.php/$0 [L]

# Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT]
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The [Apache Migration document](http://wikis.sun.com/display/WebServer/Apache+Migration+Part+4) probably has enough info to set you on the right course.

There's a [forum thread](http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=5416390) (where I found the link) which might be handy too.